# OpenLayers3 how to write tile to local storage

Tags: openlayers-3, offline-caching, angular-openlayers

I am making a app project with Openlayers 3. There are several pages which all use map. So I want to write tile to local storage when the user operate some map. When the user operate the map of the next page, I want to first search the local storage to find cached tiles, if not, get the tiles from online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a small number of tiles, you can use the [HTML5 appcache](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp):

Just add a reference in your html file:

```
<html manifest="example.appcache">
  ...
</html>
```

Where example.appcache would contain the files to be cached:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
/theme.css
/logo.gif
/main.js
```

Note that browsers may have different size limits for cached data (some browsers have a 5MB limit per site).

Whereas application cache is considered deprecated, its replacement, [service workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API), are [not widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=serviceworkers) at the moment.